# Sorting mutable array by dictionary key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have already looked through a few answers using the various sorting methods of `NSMutableArray`, but for some reason they are not working for me.

I am just trying to sort the mutable array which contains dictionaries by the `Delay` key within each dictionary.  However, the "sorted" array is the exact same as the original array.

By the way, it works fine if I create a dummy mutable array and populate it with dictionaries containing numbers, but for some reason it won't sort this mutable array that I am initializing.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
playlistCalls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[currentPlaylist objectForKey:@"Tunes"]];

NSLog(@"original %@", playlistCalls);

NSSortDescriptor *delay = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Delay" ascending:YES];
[playlistCalls sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:delay]];

NSLog(@"sorted %@", playlistCalls);
```

Here's the array containing the dictionaries:

```
2012-06-04 15:48:09.129 MyApp[57043:f503] original (
        {
        Name = Test Tune;
        Delay = 120;
        Volume = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Testes;
        Delay = 180;
        Volume = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Testing;
        Delay = 60;
        Volume = 100;
    }
)

2012-06-04 15:48:09.129 MyApp[57043:f503] sorted (
        {
        Name = Test Tune;
        Delay = 120;
        Volume = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Testes;
        Delay = 180;
        Volume = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = Testing;
        Delay = 60;
        Volume = 100;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code above is fine when I use `NSNumber`s in my dictionary. That leads me to believe that the `Delay` value is stored as strings in your dictionary. What you will need to do then is sort by the strings `integerValue`.

```
NSSortDescriptor *delay = 
   [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Delay.integerValue" ascending:YES];
```

Comment: Right you are... That did the trick.  I need to go back and fix that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following, it worked with me

```
NSDictionary *dic;
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:120], @"Delay",
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], @"Volume",
       nil];
[arr addObject:dic];

dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:160], @"Delay",
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], @"Volume",
       nil];
[arr addObject:dic];

dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], @"Delay",
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], @"Volume",
       nil];
[arr addObject:dic];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Delay" ascending:YES];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

Comment: It works when you init the mutable array and add dictionaries like that, but why doesn't it work for my case when I already have a pre-populated mutable array?  That's what I'm stuck on :\

Comment: Thanks, but I was a dummy and stored them as strings.  Joe caught it and gave me a fix.  Thanks all the same!